# change form with button radio

Tags: javascript, jquery, prestashop

I would like to be able to change form according to the check box my first form:

```
<form action="{$link->getPageLink('authentication', true)|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" method="post"
              id="login_form" class="box">
            <h3 class="page-subheading connect_or">{l s='ou'}</h3>
            <div class="form_content clearfix">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">{l s='Entrez votre email :'}</label>
                    <input class="is_required validate account_input form-control" data-validate="isEmail"
                           type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Ex: etudiant@email.fr"
                           value="{if isset($smarty.post.email)}{$smarty.post.email|stripslashes}{/if}"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label>
                            <input id="radio_login" type="radio" name="optionsRadios" value="option1">
                            Je suis un nouveau client <em>(vous pourrez créer un compte par la suite)</em>
                        </label>
                        <br>
                        <label>
                            <input id="radio_login" type="radio" name="optionsRadios" value="option2">
                            J'ai déjà un compte et un mot de passe
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="account_passwd">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="passwd">{l s='Votre mot de passe :'}</label>
                    <input class="is_required validate account_input form-control" type="password"
                           data-validate="isPasswd" id="passwd" name="passwd" value="" placeholder="*******"/>
                </div>
                <p class="lost_password form-group"><a href="{$link->getPageLink('password')|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}"
                                                       title="{l s='Recover your forgotten password'}"
                                                       rel="nofollow">{l s='Forgot your password?'}</a></p>
                </div>
                <p class="submit">
                    {if isset($back)}<input type="hidden" class="hidden" name="back"
                                            value="{$back|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" />{/if}
                    <button type="submit" id="SubmitLogin" name="SubmitLogin"
                            class="button btn btn-default button-medium">
                        <span>
                            {l s='valider'}
                        </span>
                    </button>
                </p>
            </div>
        </form>
```

My second form:

```
<form action="{$link->getPageLink('authentication', true)|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" method="post" id="create-account_form" class="box">
            <div class="form_content clearfix">
                <p>{l s='Please enter your email address to create an account.'}</p>
                <div class="alert alert-danger" id="create_account_error" style="display:none"></div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email_create">{l s='Email address'}</label>
                    <input type="email" class="is_required validate account_input form-control" data-validate="isEmail" id="email_create" name="email_create" value="{if isset($smarty.post.email_create)}{$smarty.post.email_create|stripslashes}{/if}" />
                </div>
                <div class="submit">
                    {if isset($back)}<input type="hidden" class="hidden" name="back" value="{$back|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" />{/if}
                    <button class="button btn btn-default button-medium" type="submit" id="SubmitCreate" name="SubmitCreate">
                        <span>
                            <i class="icon-user left"></i>
                            {l s='Create an account'}
                        </span>
                    </button>
                    <input type="hidden" class="hidden" name="SubmitCreate" value="{l s='Create an account'}" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label>
                            <input id="radio_create" type="radio" name="optionsRadios1" value="option1">
                            Je suis un nouveau client <em>(vous pourrez créer un compte par la suite)</em>
                        </label>
                        <br>
                        <label>
                            <input id="radio_create" type="radio" name="optionsRadios1" value="option2">
                            J'ai déjà un compte et un mot de passe
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

The condition for displaying one or the other is:

If the client selects the radio button "option1" it displays the form id = "new_account_form" otherwise the form id = "login_form".

Thank you

Comment: Where is your code that shows the problem you're having?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a change handler to your radio button.

`jQuery('#my_radiobutton').on('change', function() { /* Your code here */});`

Once it is clicked, check which option is selected.
Then use hide() or show() on the forms you want to show/hide.

[jQuery Hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) and [jQuery Show](http://api.jquery.com/show/)

This even comes with animation for eye candy.

Answer (score 0):

This code will do what you need:

```js
$('#login_form').hide();
$('#create-account_form').hide();
$('.rs').on('change',function(){
 if($(this).val() == 1){
   $('#login_form').show();
    $('#create-account_form').hide();  
  }else{
  $('#create-account_form').show();  
    $('#login_form').hide();
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class='rs' name='action' value='1' type='radio'>
<input class='rs' name='action' value='2' type='radio'>
<form action="{$link->getPageLink('authentication', true)|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" method="post" id="create-account_form" class="box" style="display:none">
            <div class="form_content clearfix">
                <p>{l s='Please enter your email address to create an account.'}</p>
                <div class="alert alert-danger" id="create_account_error" style="display:none"></div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email_create">{l s='Email address'}</label>
                    <input type="email" class="is_required validate account_input form-control" data-validate="isEmail" id="email_create" name="email_create" value="{if isset($smarty.post.email_create)}{$smarty.post.email_create|stripslashes}{/if}" />
                </div>
                <div class="submit">
                    {if isset($back)}<input type="hidden" class="hidden" name="back" value="{$back|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" />{/if}
                    <button class="button btn btn-default button-medium" type="submit" id="SubmitCreate" name="SubmitCreate">
                        <span>
                            <i class="icon-user left"></i>
                            {l s='Create an account'}
                        </span>
                    </button>
                    <input type="hidden" class="hidden" name="SubmitCreate" value="{l s='Create an account'}" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label>
                            <input id="radio_create" type="radio" name="optionsRadios1" value="option1">
                            Je suis un nouveau client <em>(vous pourrez créer un compte par la suite)</em>
                        </label>
                        <br>
                        <label>
                            <input id="radio_create" type="radio" name="optionsRadios1" value="option2">
                            J'ai déjà un compte et un mot de passe
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        
        
        
        <form action="{$link->getPageLink('authentication', true)|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" method="post"
              id="login_form" class="box" style="display:none">
            <h3 class="page-subheading connect_or">{l s='ou'}</h3>
            <div class="form_content clearfix">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">{l s='Entrez votre email :'}</label>
                    <input class="is_required validate account_input form-control" data-validate="isEmail"
                           type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Ex: etudiant@email.fr"
                           value="{if isset($smarty.post.email)}{$smarty.post.email|stripslashes}{/if}"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label>
                            <input id="radio_login" type="radio" name="optionsRadios" value="option1">
                            Je suis un nouveau client <em>(vous pourrez créer un compte par la suite)</em>
                        </label>
                        <br>
                        <label>
                            <input id="radio_login" type="radio" name="optionsRadios" value="option2">
                            J'ai déjà un compte et un mot de passe
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="account_passwd">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="passwd">{l s='Votre mot de passe :'}</label>
                    <input class="is_required validate account_input form-control" type="password"
                           data-validate="isPasswd" id="passwd" name="passwd" value="" placeholder="*******"/>
                </div>
                <p class="lost_password form-group"><a href="{$link->getPageLink('password')|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}"
                                                       title="{l s='Recover your forgotten password'}"
                                                       rel="nofollow">{l s='Forgot your password?'}</a></p>
                </div>
                <p class="submit">
                    {if isset($back)}<input type="hidden" class="hidden" name="back"
                                            value="{$back|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" />{/if}
                    <button type="submit" id="SubmitLogin" name="SubmitLogin"
                            class="button btn btn-default button-medium">
                        <span>
                            {l s='valider'}
                        </span>
                    </button>
                </p>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: our solutions are well the worry is that my radio buttons must be in my form can you do in what way for them to be? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by showing and hiding divs"

```js
 var  newaccountradio = document.getElementById('new_account_form'),
  loginradio = document.getElementById('login_form'),
 logindiv = document.getElementById('login'),
  registerdiv =  document.getElementById('new_account');
  logindiv.style.display = "none";
registerdiv.style.display = "none";
newaccountradio.onclick = opennewaccountform;
loginradio.onclick = openloginform;


function opennewaccountform(){
  registerdiv.style.display = "block";
  logindiv.style.display = "none"
}
function openloginform(){
    registerdiv.style.display = "none";
  logindiv.style.display = "block"
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="new_account_form">create new account
  <input type="radio" id="new_account_form" name="form"/>
    <label/>
    <label for="login_form">login to your acount
  <input type="radio" id="login_form" name="form"/>
      </label>
</form>

      <div id="new_account">
        <form action="">
        name
          <input type="text" />
         email
          <input type="email" />
        </form>
         passwor
          <input type="password" />
        <input type="submit" value="create new account " />
      </div>
  <div id="login">
      <form action="">
        name
          <input type="text" />
         email
          <input type="email" />
        </form>
        <input type="submit" value="login " />
  </div>
```

https://codepen.io/faw/pen/bWVKBQ

if you use jquery, the shorter version is already given in posted answers

Answer (score 0):

my solution

```
$('#login_form').show();
$('.rs').prop('checked', true);
$('.rs').parent().addClass('checked');
$('#create-account_form').hide();
$('.rs').on('change',function(){
    if($(this).val() == 1){
        $('#login_form').hide();
        $('#create-account_form').show();
        $('.rsa:first').prop('checked', true);
        $('.rsa:first').parent().addClass('checked');
        $('.rsa:last').prop('checked', false);
        $('.rsa:last').parent().removeClass('checked');
    }else{
        $('#create-account_form').show();
        $('#login_form').hide();
    }
});
$('.rsa').on('change', function(){
    if($(this).val() == 2){
        $('#login_form').show();
        $('#create-account_form').hide();
        $('.rs:last').prop('checked', true);
        $('.rs:last').parent().addClass('checked');
        $('.rs:first').prop('checked', false);
        $('.rs:first').parent().removeClass('checked');
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<form action="{$link->getPageLink('authentication', true)|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" method="post"
              id="login_form" class="box">
            <h3 class="page-subheading connect_or">{l s='ou'}</h3>
            <div class="form_content clearfix">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">{l s='Entrez votre email :'}</label>
                    <input class="is_required validate account_input form-control" data-validate="isEmail"
                           type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Ex: etudiant@email.fr"
                           value="{if isset($smarty.post.email)}{$smarty.post.email|stripslashes}{/if}"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label>
                            <input class="rs" id="radio_login" type="radio" name="action" value="1">
                            Je suis un nouveau client <em>(vous pourrez créer un compte par la suite)</em>
                        </label>
                        <br>
                        <label>
                            <input class="rs" id="radio_login" type="radio" name="action" value="2">
                            J'ai déjà un compte et un mot de passe
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="account_passwd">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="passwd">{l s='Votre mot de passe :'}</label>
                    <input class="is_required validate account_input form-control" type="password"
                           data-validate="isPasswd" id="passwd" name="passwd" value="" placeholder="*******"/>
                </div>
                <p class="lost_password form-group"><a href="{$link->getPageLink('password')|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}"
                                                       title="{l s='Recover your forgotten password'}"
                                                       rel="nofollow">{l s='Forgot your password?'}</a></p>
                </div>
                <p class="submit">
                    {if isset($back)}<input type="hidden" class="hidden" name="back"
                                            value="{$back|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" />{/if}
                    <button type="submit" id="SubmitLogin" name="SubmitLogin"
                            class="button btn btn-default button-medium">
                        <span>
                            {l s='valider'}
                        </span>
                    </button>
                </p>
            </div>
        </form>
        <form action="{$link->getPageLink('authentication', true)|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" method="post" id="create-account_form" class="box">
            <div class="form_content clearfix">
                <p>{l s='Please enter your email address to create an account.'}</p>
                <div class="alert alert-danger" id="create_account_error" style="display:none"></div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email_create">{l s='Email address'}</label>
                    <input type="email" class="is_required validate account_input form-control" data-validate="isEmail" id="email_create" name="email_create" value="{if isset($smarty.post.email_create)}{$smarty.post.email_create|stripslashes}{/if}" />
                </div>
                <div class="submit">
                    {if isset($back)}<input type="hidden" class="hidden" name="back" value="{$back|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" />{/if}
                    <button class="button btn btn-default button-medium" type="submit" id="SubmitCreate" name="SubmitCreate">
                        <span>
                            <i class="icon-user left"></i>
                            {l s='Create an account'}
                        </span>
                    </button>
                    <input type="hidden" class="hidden" name="SubmitCreate" value="{l s='Create an account'}" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label>
                            <input class="rsa" id="radio_login" type="radio" name="action" value="1">
                            Je suis un nouveau client <em>(vous pourrez créer un compte par la suite)</em>
                        </label>
                        <br>
                        <label>
                            <input class="rsa" id="radio_login" type="radio" name="action" value="2">
                            J'ai déjà un compte et un mot de passe
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```